# Requests fail authorization when query string contains certain characters

Tags: swift, twitter, oauth, postman

I'm making requests to Twitter, using the `OAuth1.0` signing process to set the `Authorization` header. They explain it step-by-step [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-1-0a/authorizing-a-request), which I've followed. It all works, *most of the time*.

Authorization fails whenever *special* characters are sent *without* percent encoding in the query component of the request. For example, `?status=hello%20world!` fails, but `?status=hello%20world%21` succeeds. But the change from `!` to the percent encoded form `%21` is only made in the URL, *after* the signature is generated.

So I'm confused as to why this fails, because AFAIK that's a legally encoded query string. Only the raw strings `("status", "hello world!")` are used for signature generation, and I'd assume the server would remove any percent encoding from the query params and generate its own signature for comparison.

When it comes to building the URL, I let `URLComponents` do the work, so I don't add percent encoding manually, ex.

```
var urlComps = URLComponents()
urlComps.scheme = "https"
urlComps.host = host
urlComps.path = path
urlComps.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(key: "status", value: "hello world!")]
urlComps.percentEncodedQuery // "status=hello%20world!"
```

I wanted to see how Postman handled the same request. I selected `OAuth1.0` as the Auth type and plugged in the same credentials. The request succeeded. I checked the Postman console and saw `?status=hello%20world%21`; it was percent encoding the `!`. I updated Postman, because a nice little prompt asked me to. Then I tried the same request; now it was getting an authorization failure, and I saw `?status=hello%20world!` in the console; the `!` was no longer being percent encoded.

I'm wondering who is at fault here. Perhaps Postman and I are making the same mistake. Perhaps it's with Twitter. Or perhaps there's some proxy along the way that idk, double encodes my `!`.

The `OAuth1.0` [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849) says this, which I believe is in the context of both client (taking a request that's ready to go and signing it before it's sent), and server (for generating another signature to compare against the one received):

> The parameters from the following sources are collected into a
> single    list of name/value pairs:
>
> - The query component of the HTTP request URI as defined by
>   [RFC3986], Section 3.4.  The query component is parsed into a list
>   of name/value pairs by treating it as an
>   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" string, separating the names
>   and values and decoding them as defined by
>   [W3C.REC-html40-19980424], Section 17.13.4.

That last reference, [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-html40-19980424/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4), outlines the encoding for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, and says that space characters should be replaced with `+`, non-alphanumeric characters should be percent encoded, name separated from value by `=`, and pairs separated by `&`.

So, the `OAuth1.0` spec says that the query string of the URL needs to be **decoded** as defined by `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Does that mean that our query string needs to be **encoded** this way too?

It *seems* to me, if a request is to be signed using `OAuth1.0`, the query component of the URL that gets sent must be encoded in a way that is different to what it would normally be encoded in? That's a pretty significant detail if you ask me. And I haven't seen it explicitly mentioned, even in Twitter's documentation. And evidently the folks at Postman overlooked it too? Unless I'm not supposed to be using `URLComponents` to build a URL, but that's what it's for, no? Have I understood this correctly?

Note: `?status=hello+world%21` succeeds; it tweets "hello world!"

Comment: Postman doesn’t seem to encode OAuth 1.0a requests correctly.

Comment: @AndyPiper Could the issue be on Twitter's end? Because, from my own code (not Postman), I can send 2 requests with identical `Authorization` headers (same signature, nonce, timestamp etc), only difference being that one is sent as `?status=hello!` and the other as `?status=hello%21`. Only the latter succeeds.

Comment: The issue is the encoding.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue.

1. put the status in post body, not query string.
2. Percent-encoding:

   ```
    private encode(str: string) {
    // encodeURIComponent() escapes all characters except: A-Z a-z 0-9 - _ . ! ~ * " ( )
    // RFC 3986 section 2.3 Unreserved Characters (January 2005): A-Z a-z 0-9 - _ . ~ 
    return encodeURIComponent(str)
        .replace(/[!'()*]/g, c => "%" + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).toUpperCase());
   ```

   }